# Logging in each method vs Logging with Aspect?

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, design-patterns, aop

Whenever I write an API or program with Spring Boot, my logging strategy is usually like below:

```
@Service
public class ShortLinkServiceImpl implements ShortLinkService {
   
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Override
    public String getByHashCode(String hashCode)
            throws HashCodeExpiredException, LinkNotFoundException {
          log.info("getByHashCode -> hashCode: {}", hashCode);
         ...
         ...
         //if necessary
         log.info("getByHashCode -> result: {}", result);
    }
}
```

However, adding `log.info` into each method in my API does not look like a good approach (at least for me).

Is there any way to write more clean logging strategy, I am thinking of writing an aspect for each class that I want to log, and by using before and after joinPoint to log input and output of the methods.

To sum up, I would like to hear more about this topic whether there is a more convenient and clean way or not.

Comment: Previous comment provide a solution. Only improvement I would suggest is defining a specific  annotation like "@Loggable" as in "@Transactional", "@Cacheable" and use that annotation on class or method level to have a better control.

Answer (score 0):

*Not an answer , but too lengthy for a comment , hence posting as an answer.*

Logging is a classical example for AOP . A very detailed explanation can be read in the [**10.7. Improving conventional logging**](https://livebook.manning.com/book/aspectj-in-action-second-edition/chapter-10/187) section of the book [**AspectJ in Action, Second Edition**](https://www.manning.com/books/aspectj-in-action-second-edition).

Following are couple of points to consider , if AOP is the approach identified.

A pointcut expression , if written correctly, can target multiple classes and advice accordingly.Writing aspect for each class would not be an ideal approach. Please keep in mind that *Spring AOP* cannot target/advice a private method execution and subsequently logging as well. You will need AspectJ for more fine grained control.

[@Around advice](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop-ataspectj-around-advice) would be ideal instead of @Before and @After

As per me , this is not a real question and more of a topic open for discussion/opinions , which is not entertained in stackoverflow. Please read through this [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252854/why-doesnt-stack-overflow-allow-discussable-questions-or-questions-that-require) for more details. You may improve this to be a specific question to get an answer and not get this closed.

[Spring AOP reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop) is a good place to start.